# Permutation test, probability and FDR

Tags: multiple-comparisons, permutation-test, false-discovery-rate

I encountered a problem to perform FDR control of my data, and am not sure how can I do.

I have hundreds to thousands of observations, each observation has two scores. So I have $\mathbf{s_1}=\{s_{11}, s_{12}, ...,s_{1N}\}$ and $\mathbf{s_2}=\{s_{21}, s_{21}, ...,s_{2N}\}$, where $N$ is number of observations. *All observations and scores are independent. Two scores in same observation are also independent*.

To evaluate the significance of each score in each observation, permutation test is performed by randomly shuffling values of the observation and recalculating scores, so for observation $i$, I have random scores $\mathbf{s_{1i}^{r}} = \{s_{1i}^{1}, s_{1i}^{2},..., s_{1i}^{R}\}$ and $\mathbf{s_{2i}^{r}} = \{s_{2i}^{1}, s_{2i}^{2},..., s_{2i}^{R}\}$, where $R$ is number of permutations. $R=10000$. Then $p$-value of permutation test for the two scores of observation $i$ are estimated by $p_{1i}=Pr(s_{1i}^{r}>=s_{1i})$ and $p_{2i}=Pr(s_{2i}^{r}>=s_{2i})$, where $Pr$ is CDF. I used Weibull distribution to fit the distribution of random scores.

The question is how can I perform [FDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) control to the dataset? Can I use $p_i=p_{1i}*p_{2i}$ as the overall $p$-value of the observation $i$ and then use for example [BH Procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Benjamini%E2%80%93Hochberg_procedure) with specified [FDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) level, say $0.01$, to select significant observations? If not, where should I go?

Comment: At least to me, the question isn't clear.  When you say, "Then the p-value for all scores are estimated", The p-value for what hypothesis?

Comment: @SalMangiafico has been revised.

Comment: Why are you doing permutations? Why aren't you just ranking the observations?

Comment: @t.f I want to use the FDR to control my dataset. This can not be achieved using only scores. So I use permutation test to get the significance of each score and use BH correction to get the list of observations with FDR of 0.01. This procedure is commonly used and required in my research field.

Comment: I still don't get it, but that may not matter...  In any case, the BH procedure is applied for the number of hypotheses you are testing.  If p1i and p2i correspond to different hypotheses you are testing, then you have 2N hypotheses and so 2N p-values to use in the BH procedure.  If p1i and p2i somehow are used in the same hypothesis, you have N hypotheses and so N p-values to use in the BH procedure.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thanks. But I can't get what the "same hypothesis" means. Two scores for each observation come from different resources and do not correlate to each other. Of course I can use such as linear combination to integrate them into single score and then perform permutation test to it. But I would like to consider them separately. I think this is something like perform two multiple comparisons using $p_1$ and $p_2$ independently. In your cases, what should I do? Use $p_i = min(p_{1i}, p_{2i})$? Or Use $p_i = max(p_{1i}, p_{2i})$?

Comment: Any decision you make corresponds to a hypothesis.  If you are concluding that "a score is significant", then that constitutes a decision.  But I really don't understand what you are trying to do, so I can't be sure of my advice.  Off hand, I can't imagine any case in which two p-values would be combined by either multiplying, taking the minimum, or taking the maximum, for a hypothesis test.  I also don't know what testing for the "significance of each score" would mean...  It may help to ask a new question and give an example with some numbers, or consult with someone knowledgeable...